# Intellij idea script error : The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: intellij-idea

Shell script showing error : **The system cannot find the path specified.** in Intellij Idea on running script from **get_book.sh** file

[image]

In terminal script run with absolute path

[image]

Comment: You don't have `/bin/sh` on Windows

Comment: script run if directly run through terminal, But in file it give full path to run instead of just : curl localhost:8080/book/

Comment: As I said earlier you don't have `/bin/sh` on Windows as it's a feature of Unix-like operation systems. You should rename `get_book.sh` to `get_book.bat` and run from terminal simply `get_book.bat`. Assuming that you've already installed cURL for Windows